# Error: Storage size of a isn't known

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I have been searching for the problem with this code but I'm just not sure what to do now. I was doing some practice with structures in C.

It's intended to be a program that gets the values of 2 integers and adds them and stores the value in `sum` and then print `sum`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        int num;
        int num2;
        int sum;
    } calc;

    struct calc a;

    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a.num);

    printf("\nEnter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a.num2);

    a.sum=a.num+a.num2;

    printf("Output: %d", a.sum);

    return 0;
}
```

> Error: Storage size of a isn't known.

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef struct {
    int num;
    int num2;
    int sum;
} calc;
```

Here, you are giving an anomymous structure an alias of `calc`, so there's no such structure called `struct calc`. You should define `a` as:

```
calc a;
```

Or, you can give your structure a tag:

```
typedef struct calc {
    int num;
    int num2;
    int sum;
} calc;
```

Now you can use either `calc` or `struct calc`.

Comment: Thanks. Should've noticed that I was creating a new structure instead of using one. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have `typedef`'ed your struct, so when you declare it, just use `calc` instead of `struct calc`.

Change `struct calc a;` to `calc a;`